# C# Web Browser Bot question

Tags: c#, .net, browser, bots

I want to do web browser bot. It should click link and wait 25 seconds.

```
    private void webBrowserMain_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) // This is only way It worked for me.
    {
        if (webBrowserMain.Url.AbsoluteUri == @"http://www.clix-cents.com/pages/clickads")
        {
            Regex regAddId = new Regex("onclick=\\'openad\\(\"([\\d\\w]+)\"\\);", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // Find link and click it.
            if (regAddId.IsMatch(webBrowserMain.DocumentText))
            {
                string AddId = regAddId.Match(webBrowserMain.DocumentText).Groups[1].ToString();
                webBrowserMain.Navigate(@"http://www.clix-cents.com/pages/clickads?h=" + AddId);
            }
        }
        else if (webBrowserMain.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("http://www.clix-cents.com/pages/clickads?h=")) // up to there everything is ok. But problem starts here.
        {
            Thread.Sleep(25000); // It pouses whole thread and browser, so timer in browser is not counting down.
            Regex regCaptchaCode = new Regex("src=\\'/pages/captcha\\?t=c&s=([\\d\\w\\W]+)\\'", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (regCaptchaCode.IsMatch(webBrowserMain.DocumentText))
            {
                pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"http://www.clix-cents.com/pages/captcha?t=c&s=" + regCaptchaCode.Match(webBrowserMain.DocumentText).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

How to write bot for something like that? I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel - there's already solutions out there like [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) which is mainly used for testing but is also suitable for automation.

Code example from the WatiN page:

```
[Test]
public void SearchForWatiNOnGoogle()
{
  using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
  {
    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
    browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();

    Assert.IsTrue(browser.ContainsText("WatiN"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a timer. Eg:

```
private Timer t = new Timer();
private string nextUrl = "";
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    t.Interval = 2500;
    t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
}

void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextUrl))
        webBrowser1.Navigate(nextUrl);
    else
    {
        Regex regCaptchaCode = new Regex("src=\\'/pages/captcha\\?t=c&s=([\\d\\w\\W]+)\\'", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (regCaptchaCode.IsMatch(webBrowserMain.DocumentText))
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"http://www.clix-cents.com/pages/captcha?t=c&s=" + regCaptchaCode.Match(webBrowserMain.DocumentText).ToString();
        }
    }
}
private void webBrowserMain_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) // This is only way It worked for me.
{
    if (webBrowserMain.Url.AbsoluteUri == @"http://www.clix-cents.com/pages/clickads")
    {
        Regex regAddId = new Regex("onclick=\\'openad\\(\"([\\d\\w]+)\"\\);", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // Find link and click it.
        if (regAddId.IsMatch(webBrowserMain.DocumentText))
        {
            string AddId = regAddId.Match(webBrowserMain.DocumentText).Groups[1].ToString();
            nextUrl = @"http://www.clix-cents.com/pages/clickads?h=" + AddId;
            t.Start();
        }
    }
    else if (webBrowserMain.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("http://www.clix-cents.com/pages/clickads?h=")) // up to there everything is ok. But problem starts here.
    {
        nextUrl = "";
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

The actual implementation will depend on the actual data on the site and how you want to use it. If all the links are on one page and you want to open each one, you could parse for all the links and store into a list. Then start the timer. At each Tick, you could open 1 item.